# Is there a Python MySQL API that returns Prepared Statements for re-use?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, prepared-statement

Neither [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) nor [oursql](http://pythonhosted.org/oursql/) allow returning [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to be filled by parameters for successive executions. Are there any others?

At least for `.executemany()` *oursql* seems to be more proficient than *MySQLdb* as the SQL statement is only prepared once for all submitted values.

(Does Python support preparation and re-use of Prepared Statements with PostgreSQL?)

Comment: better is entirely subjective.,  I think that PostgreSQL is generally better but there are some things that MySQL really excels at.

Comment: removing the subjective 'better' in lieu of prepared statement support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your PostgreSQL question, the answer is there is no Python-specific way to handle prepared statements at least as of last October (I am not a Python programmer but this is fairly common across languages).  PostgreSQL offers however an SQL-language way to do this so any language can use prepared statements if SQL queries can be executed.  For code examples on how to do this in Python, see http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2012/10/01/prepared-statements-psycopg/

There are a couple of major caveats though.  One of them is that prepared statements are planned on first run, and the plan is re-used.  This works great for queries where the same plan is uniformly required (say, simple inserts) but it causes problems where parameters might change enough that new plans might be required.  So the following are likely to be ok in most cases(there are still nasty corner cases to be aware of):

1. `INSERT INTO foo (bar) values ($1)`
2. `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar= $1;` assuming that bar is the primary key

Something like the following may not be safe:

1. `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar < $1`
2. `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE baz = $1` where baz may have a significant portion of rows with the same value.